# Format a csv file with a macro

Tags: csv, import, excel-2010, ms-access-2010

I have a .csv file that I am exporting from our accounting software.  The ultimate goal is to import "some" of that data into an Access 2010 database table by appending records.  My issue is that I need some sort of apparatus to select only choice fields from the .csv file and format those fields (define datatypes) so that I am then able to import the "new" formated .csv into Access, appending to an existing table, without any errors.

Our accounting software does allow specific fields from their datafile to be exported, but it is a cumbersome process and likely to present many opportunities for errors by the Customer Service department.  I need to make this a "idiot-proof" as possible!

Comment: Could you transfer it into excel first, delete the columns that you don't need, then export the excel spreadsheet back to csv?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, please provide your code. If not, please attempt solving this and we can further assist you with the issues you get stuck on. It's also difficult to help without some sort of sample data defining what `choice fields` you mean.

Comment: I tried the Import From Text function in Excel.  What I would like to do is automate what I am able to achieve manually, probably by using a macro of some kind.

Comment: @Sam For example, the csv file contains 40 fields.  I am only interested in the data in 9 of those (choice) fields.  But they have to be formatted in the correct datatype to be able to import and append them to an existing table in Access.

Comment: what languages / limitations do you have in this? Can you write a console app or service that will parse through the directory these are csv's are stored in, modify them and output them in an output directory? Do you need to change which rows are imported based on what the file contains?

Comment: @SGrimminck I think that can be accomplished within Excel without the need to write a separate console app/service.  I am just not sure how.  I have used VBA fairly extensively to program in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query to import the CSV data directly into your Access table.

A query will make it easy to select a subset of the available CSV fields.  And a query can include functions to transform the CSV values for compatibility with the Access destination field data types.

```sql
INSERT INTO tblFromCSV ( FK_ID, CD, [TIMESTAMP], ts_as_datetime )
SELECT
    CLng(csv.FK_ID),
    UCase(csv.CD),
    csv.TIMESTAMP,
    CDate(csv.ts_as_datetime)
FROM [Text;HDR=yes;Database=C:\share\Access\].[sample.csv] AS csv;
```

The field names listed in the first line of the SQL, `INSERT INTO tblFromCSV (<here>)`, are the names of the Access table fields which will store the imported data.  If you're supplying values for all the table fields, and supplying those values in the same order as the table fields, you can omit that field list.  I generally list the fields regardless.

In the `FROM` clause, `HDR=yes` signals that the first row of my CSV source file contains field names.  If your CSV file does not, use `HDR=no`, and Access will assign fake names, such as fld1, fld2, etc., to the CSV fields.

Note that, if the CSV does include field names, they need not match the names of the Access fields.

If you build a similar query in the query designer, beware that it may alter the `FROM` clause like this ...

```sql
FROM (Text;HDR=yes;Database=C:\share\Access\) sample.csv AS csv;
```

So, if that happens, change it back to avoid a syntax error.

I suggest you start with just a `SELECT` query to get the `FROM` clause working.  Then add the functions you need to convert the CSV values as needed.  Once that `SELECT` query returns what you need, convert it into an `INSERT` query.

My hope is if a similar query can work for your situation, you won't need Excel as an intermediary to get the CSV data into Access.

Comment: This looks very promising.  Can you explain the FK_ID, CD, etc...?  Are those necessary, or is that just going to be the field names of the Access table I am appending the data to?

Comment: I think you did.  I will give it a go at work tomorrow and report back.  Thanks Hans

Comment: I should get clarification I guess.  What exactly is that From statement doing?  Obviously it points to the .csv file, but what does HDR stand for?  And does the file have to be in a shared folder?  I am assuming it would work if it is in the same directory as the Access Datafile?

Comment: So if I do not include header names in the original export of the .csv (they are hideously named), I can change that to HDR=No?

Comment: What if the CSV columns have spaces or '/' or '#' symbols in the names?  How should those be treated in the select statement?

Comment: Nevermind the last comment.  Just enclose the names in brackets works fine.

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY.  Some minor errors due to invalid data entry into the accounting software, but that is a different matter.  Thanks Hans!